# Key access in an arbitrary JSON object in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
import Text.JSON

-- get the value in a JSON object that has this key
getByKey :: JSValue -> String -> Maybe JSValue
getByKey object key =
  case object of
    JSObject a ->
      getFirst keyValues keyMatches
      where keyValues = fromJSObject object
            keyMatches (key', value) = key == key'
    _ -> Nothing

-- get the first item in the list matching a predicate
getFirst :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Maybe a
getFirst [] pred = Nothing
getFirst (x:xs) pred =
  case pred x of
    True -> Just x
    False -> getFirst xs pred
```

I want to use it to access values in an arbitrary JSValue. However, it doesn't compile:

```
Prelude> :load Example
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Example.hs, interpreted )

Example.hs:8:26:
    Couldn't match expected type `JSValue'
                with actual type `(String, t0)'
    Expected type: JSValue -> Bool
      Actual type: (String, t0) -> Bool
    In the second argument of `getFirst', namely `keyMatches'
    In the expression: getFirst keyValues keyMatches

Example.hs:9:38:
    Couldn't match expected type `JSObject e0'
                with actual type `JSValue'
    In the first argument of `fromJSObject', namely `object'
    In the expression: fromJSObject object
    In an equation for `keyValues': keyValues = fromJSObject object
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What have I done wrong?

*Edit*: Daniel Fischer kindly pointed out that `fromJSObject object` should be `fromJSObject a`. However, this isn't quite sufficient to make the type checker happy:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Example.hs, interpreted )

Example.hs:8:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `JSValue'
                with actual type `(String, JSValue)'
    Expected type: [JSValue]
      Actual type: [(String, JSValue)]
    In the first argument of `getFirst', namely `keyValues'
    In the expression: getFirst keyValues keyMatches
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply use the existing [`lookup`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3alookup) function from the Prelude?

```
getByKey :: JSValue -> String -> Maybe JSValue
getByKey (JSObject obj) key = lookup key (fromJSObject obj)
getByKey _ _ = Nothing
```

Also, your `getFirst` function is [`Data.List.find`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3afind) (with the arguments in the opposite order).

Comment: Wow, a 70% reduction in length compared with my original code! Thanks for the references to `find` and `lookup` too, that's really helpful. I'm itching to know what was wrong with my original code though.

Comment: @WilfredHughes: The problem is that the result of the call to `getFirst` returns a `Maybe (String, JSValue)` with both the key and the value. Try replacing it with `fmap snd $ getFirst keyValues keyMatches` to get a `Maybe JSValue`.

Answer (score 3):

The type of [`fromJSObject`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/json/latest/doc/html/Text-JSON.html#v%3afromJSObject) is

```
fromJSObject :: JSObject e -> [(String, e)]
```

but in the line

```
where keyValues = fromJSObject object
```

you pass it a `JSValue`. You just used the wrong identifier, directly above you deconstructed

```
case object of
  JSObject a ->
```

so your `JSObject` is `a`,

```
where keyValues = fromJSObject a
```

should work.

Also, `getFirst` is `flip find` for [`find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3afind) from `Data.List`.